# Custom view for parameters on Azure Devops pipelines build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

For some time im looking for a possibility to display parameters on build view on Azure DevOps. Unfortunately i did not found any system option to enable it. I wonder if there is a way to create a custom tab in this view to display the params used in the current build. Right now the only option of seeing the params is clicking on "Run New" button and lookup for the params used in last run. What about runtime lookup? , not possible.

The tab next to Summary, Tests called Parameters will do the trick. In example like Jenkins has it's Parameters view.

Is there any already existing way to implement such or simmilar view?

An image to imagine what view im talking about :)[image]

Looking google for already existing possibilities or info about how to implement this.

Comment: Hi, have you checked my instructions to test if you can see the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the run time parameter selected in the job log.

Pipeline summary UI -> Click the Job -> Job summary page -> Job preparation parameters
[image]

Here's the parameter defined in the test pipeline.
[image]

Another workaround is to add a script task in your pipeline to echo the parameters. So that you can check out what parameters are selected from the task log later.

```
-script:|
    echo "name ---> ${{parameters.name}}"
displayName:'Parameters Selected'
```

[image]

[image]

If you want the UI section like "Tests" view, currently there's no build in feature to achieve this, you could create a suggestion via: [Visual Studio Feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest)